# Bars not showing in D3 stacked bar chart (using json)

Tags: json, d3.js, bar-chart, stacked

Edit: The visualization now works but only with this small dataset. With my original dataset (which is at least ten times the size of the one posted below), nothing shows up in the visualization.

I have been trying to make a stacked bar chart like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 but using json instead. For some reason though, the bars will not show up. The JS code is exactly the same as the example code except for variable name changes:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)     
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json ("stats_reformat_short.json", function (error, data) {

color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Time"; }));

data.forEach(function(d) {
var y0 = 0;
d.concent = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
d.total = d.concent[d.concent.length - 1].y1;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Time; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

 svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Concentration");

var time = svg.selectAll(".time")
.data(data)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "g")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Time) + ",0)"; });

time.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d.concent; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
.data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", width - 18)
.attr("width", 0.1)
.attr("height", 0.1)
.style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", width - 24)
.attr("y", 9)
.attr("dy", ".15em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text(function(d) { return d; });

});
```

stats_reformat_short.json

```
[
  {
"Time":0,
"H2O":0.7223999972,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775999921,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":0,
"H3SiO4-":0,
"Ca++":0,
"CaOH+":0,
"OH-":0,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0,
"H2O":0.7223999972,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775999921,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":0,
"H3SiO4-":0,
"Ca++":0,
"CaOH+":0,
"OH-":0,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.1011666667,
"H2O":0.722445376,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775546219,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":1.66E-006,
"H3SiO4-":0.0007145257,
"Ca++":0.0021455429,
"CaOH+":3.01E-006,
"OH-":0.0035762526,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.2025,
"H2O":0.7224635218,
"Ca3SiO5":0.277536476,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":5.77E-006,
"H3SiO4-":0.000996856,
"Ca++":0.0029978343,
"CaOH+":1.00E-005,
"OH-":0.0049973131,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.3038333333,
"H2O":0.7224757574,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775242411,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":1.19E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.001183896,
"Ca++":0.0035669817,
"CaOH+":2.03E-005,
"OH-":0.005946632,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.4051666667,
"H2O":0.722485082,
"Ca3SiO5":0.277514916,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":1.92E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0013237783,
"Ca++":0.0039957417,
"CaOH+":3.31E-005,
"OH-":0.0066624743,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.5065,
"H2O":0.7224926814,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775073166,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":2.77E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0014351806,
"Ca++":0.0043407829,
"CaOH+":4.80E-005,
"OH-":0.0072388754,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.611,
"H2O":0.7224993205,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2775006773,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":3.68E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0015308949,
"Ca++":0.0046383714,
"CaOH+":6.48E-005,
"OH-":0.0077369817,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.7155,
"H2O":0.7225050948,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2774949035,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":4.60E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0016128709,
"Ca++":0.0048938526,
"CaOH+":8.27E-005,
"OH-":0.0081655806,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.82,
"H2O":0.7225102312,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2774897666,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":5.54E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0016845349,
"Ca++":0.0051181417,
"CaOH+":0.0001016937,
"OH-":0.0085426217,
"Vacancy":"0"
},
{
"Time":0.9245,
"H2O":0.722514876,
"Ca3SiO5":0.2774851215,
"Ca(OH)2":0,
"CSH(II)":0,
"H2SiO4--":6.52E-005,
"H3SiO4-":0.0017480743,
"Ca++":0.0053181429,
"CaOH+":0.0001216663,
"OH-":0.0088794869,
"Vacancy":"0"
}
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Works for me -- https://vida.io/documents/TzxgJ25d4zShXFe2u

Comment: Huh. Maybe it's my browser-Oh I see I think it just took too much time to load >.< My actual data is a lot larger, and that definitely doesn't show up. Any suggestions on how to modify the code so it does show?

Comment: Broken data? The code should be fine really. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Nope, just that the labels for time get all smooshed into the middle and none of the bars show. I would update my data code but it might take up too much space.

Comment: Feel free to update the vida document I've linked to with the full data.

Comment: Here, this is the vida with my full data: https://vida.io/documents/W4KmdTyxCAJgMRmfv

Comment: All your rectangles are there -- they just have zero width!  You are trying to squish so much data into that space that `.rangeRoundBands()` must be rounding everything down to zero.  You need to figure out another design -- there's no way you can draw >3000 bars in a chart on a screen that is (for most viewers) fewer than that many pixels wide.

Comment: P.S.  For starters, try a stacked area chart as a better option for that much data.

Comment: You can see what Amelia means if you increase the width of the graph -- https://vida.io/documents/ysZctcKXdSyyuDygu There's an offset at the start, but obviously it isn't really viable even ignoring that.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you, I thought it was an error in my code, but obviously it's just that my chart is not suitable for the data I'm trying to visualize. Thank you!